# MySQL-Link Error in php function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am beginner in php . and i have this Sql problem:

```
function InsertUserBirdsFromFile($File_content){
for($i =0; $i < count($File_content); $i+=2){
$id = $this->Master_file($File_content[$i], $File_content[$i + 1] );
if(isset($id)){
try{
$qry = "insert into user_to_birds(user_id,tax_id)values( 1 ,'.$id .') ";
         $result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection);

}
catch(Exception $ex){ echo  $ex;}
}
}
}

function Master_file($name, $latin ){
try{

 $qry = "SELECT tax_id FROM  master where name =".$name." and latin =".$latin;
         $result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection);
        }
        catch(Exception $ex){ return null;}
                        if ($result == true && mysql_num_rows($result) >0) {
                        $p=0;
                          while ($Res_user = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
                        $marques[$p] = $Res_user;
                        $p++;
                        }
                        return $marques[0]['tax_id'];
                        }
                        else return null;
}
```

the error shown is : `Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/admin/public_html/hitlist/include/fg_membersite.php on line 427`
in this line `$result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection);`.

what is the problem? How can i fix it?

Comment: Could you try it like this mysql_query($qry); It says $this->connection does not refer to a valid mysql-connection link resource

Comment: Check out function where connection to your database is established. Also `var_dump($this->connection)` so as to check out it's value.

Comment: how to know the host from the phpMyAdmin

Comment: Shows up on the right hand column, on the top. http://tinypic.com/r/1scv2a/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe unrelated but i think this needs to be fixed

```
$qry = "insert into user_to_birds(user_id,tax_id)values( 1 ,'.$id .') "
```

to

```
$qry = "insert into user_to_birds(user_id,tax_id)values( 1 ,".$id .") "
```

or

```
$qry = "insert into user_to_birds(user_id,tax_id)values( 1 ,$id) "
```